# Javascript mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

I am have problems with my HTML5 / Javascript game. On my first menu i have a function "mouseClicked" which gives me exact X and Y coordinates and when i click in an area which i have bordered the game will start... This runs perfectly but when the game finishes and my finish screen pops up i want to click a button but it simply doesnt work. My console is saying that it cannot read the property of "pageX" of undefinied

here is a view from section that keeps bothering me.. I am very new to programming so please be patient with me :P Can i use twice function that scans my coordinates ? :o

```
function mouseClicked(e) {
mouseX = e.pageX - canvasBg.offsetLeft;
mouseY = e.pageY - canvasBg.offsetTop;
if (Playing == false && over == false) {
    if (btnPlay.checkClicked()) {  //this works great
        playGame();
    }
}
if (Playing == false && over == true)
    if (btnPlayAgain.checkClicked()) {
        init();
    }

}

function mouseClicked2(e) {
mouseX = e.pageX - canvasFinish.offsetLeft;
mouseY = e.pageY - canvasFinish.offsetTop;
if (isPlaying == false && over == true)
    if (btnPlayAgain.checkClicked()) {   // cannot load pageX 
        init();
    }
```

}

Comment: Yes you can, but what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: When i press the area in the last picture i want the loop therefore the game to start again... i find F5 a bit less attractive :D

Comment: You seem to be missing some closing braces - namely, a closing brace for `if (Playing == false && over == true)`. You're also missing an opening brace there.

Comment: You can call mouseClicked2(e) at the end of mouseClicked() and pass the event.

Comment: how do you pass the event ? 
    function mouseClicked(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - canvasBg.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - canvasBg.offsetTop;
        if (isPlaying == false && over == false) {
            if (btnPlay.checkClicked()) {
                playGame();
            }
    }
    if (isPlaying == false && over == true) {
        if (btnPlayAgain.checkClicked()) {
            init();
        }        
    }
}

i tried to put the second function into the first one but it didnt work ... still problem with pageX

Comment: @Termininja, not sure if removing a "thanks" is worth the revival of this 3 y-o question which looks like a typo anyway.